# Memory allocation process in C? Is it top down or bottom-up approach

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, allocation

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{
    int a,b,*p,*q; 
    a=10; b=5; p=&a; q=&b; 
    float c=3.4, d=4.3, *r,*t;
    r=&c; t=&d; 
    char s='o'; 
    printf("address of a=%u\n",p); 
    printf("address of b=%u\n",q);
    printf("address of c=%u\n",r); 
    printf("address of d=%u\n",t); 
    printf("address of s=%u\n",&s); 
    return 0; 
}
```

with these code output like

```
address of a=1999992860
address of b=1999992856
address of c=1999992852
address of d=1999992848
address of s=1999992847
```

If memory allocation is in top down approach then how can 'd' take 1 byte being a float variable?

If it is bottom up approach which is not actually taken then it is okay.

Now if I will consider that bottom up approach is done,then by making a change in the code that is place `char s='o'`

Before initialising `int a,b`, it will give some different result.

```
address of `a=2987907272`
address of `b=2987907268`
address of `c=2987907264`
address of `d=2987907260`
address of `s=2987907279`
```

Please help.

Comment: The allocation process is not specified by C - it varies with implementations.

Comment: Please explain your conclusion that `d` takes 1 byte. Also please explain what you mean by the terms "top down" and "bottom up" in this context. Third, please explain how you think that (whatever it is) influences or constrains the sizes of variables. Note: if this is not done then the question is likely to be closed as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Oh. Finally my telepathy circuit worked! I think you're asking whether the reported address of a variable is **start-address** or **end-address**. It's the former, a start address, with the object occupying bytes at consecutively increasing addresses. I'll post this as answer, so sure am I of the ESP. :-)

Comment: The op has confused many terms, e.g by memory allocation, they mean stack use. They also seem to think endianess is different for stack objects.

Comment: don't print addresses with format `"%u"`, `unsigned` and pointers will  often not have the same width, `"%p"` and casting the pointer to `void*` would be correct.

Comment: I can't figure out what the actual question here is.

Comment: Variables are allocated in stack from highest to lowest addresses.in 1st output memory location is assigned from 19999992860 then 56 then 52 then 48.as they are taking 4bytes memory.but 'd' is also declared as integer.therefore s should start from 1999992844.According to this d occupies only 1 byte memory.How?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking whether the reported address of a variable is **start-address** or **end-address**. It's the former, a start address. The object occupying bytes at consecutively increasing addresses.

However, do note that the Holy Standard does not constrain an object to reside in consecutive bytes, but instead talks about a *region* of storage which, especially in order to support multiple virtual inheritance, can be non-contiguous.

In practice, however, a most derived object occupies contiguous storage.

Comment: one can also argue that regions of memory that appear to be adjacent in the eyes of your program, in reality are not, because of the security features adopted by the kernel and hardware on your platform of choice. I'm curious about why one would like to predict this kind of behaviours .

Comment: @user2485710: you should post a new question about "why one would like to predict this kind of behaviors", where "this kind" includes logical to physical address translation. Reasons to delve into that include, as always, efficiency (of paging), but it's totally unrelated to the OP's question, and totally unrelated to the standard's possibly non-contiguous regions, and too much to discuss in comments. So, do post a new question. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your first output the variable `s` occupies 1 byte at 1999992847. Variable `d` occupies range of bytes starting from 1999992848 and up till 1999992851.

In any case you should always consider assigned address as result of some magic. Compiler is absolutely free to reorder variables, allocate them in one order or another, apply padding, etc.

**Update:**

Address of the variable is ALWAYS a beginning of its area. Regardless of the direction of allocation.

```
             +----------------------+
1999992847:  |       s              |
             +----------------------+
1999992848:  |       d              |
1999992849:  |                      |
1999992850:  |                      |
1999992851:  |                      |
             +----------------------+
1999992852:  |       c              |
1999992853:  |                      |
1999992854:  |                      |
1999992855:  |                      |
             +----------------------+
1999992856:  |       b              |
1999992857:  |                      |
1999992858:  |                      |
1999992859:  |                      |
```

Comment: variables are allocated in stack from highest to lowest addresses.in 1st output memory location is assigned from 19999992860 then 56 then 52 then 48.as they are taking 4bytes memory.but 'd' is also declared as integer.therefore s should start from 1999992844.According to this d occupies only 1 byte memory.How?If we considered padding then the second output is okay.but why padding is required?

Comment: Please, take a look at my picture. Address of the variable is ALWAYS a beginning of its area. Your second dump is unclear. You are not giving the exact code that generated it.